# Using Session ID for username INSERT in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to run a Query at the moment, i've managed to get it working with just adding the exact username but when I try and use the current query to use the $_Session identified username it dosn't work.

```
<?php 
    include ("config.php"); 
    session_start();    
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $stmt = $db->exec ("UPDATE users SET lastlogindate = NOW() WHERE username = '$username'");
?>
```

EDIT - Login.php code

```
<?php 
    require("config.php"); 
    $submitted_username = ''; 
    if(!empty($_POST)){ 
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                id, 
                username, 
                password, 
                salt, 
                email 
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                username = :username 
        "; 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
        ); 

        try{ 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); } 
        $login_ok = false; 
        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
        if($row){ 
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
            for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++){
                $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']);
            } 
            if($check_password === $row['password']){
                $login_ok = true;
            } 
        } 

        if($login_ok){ 
            unset($row['salt']); 
            unset($row['password']);
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row;
            header("Location: main.php"); 
            die("Redirecting to: main.php");    
        } 
        else{ 
            print("Login Failed."); 
            $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
        } 
    }; 
?>
```

Comment: Use prepared statements and not just that error might go away.

Comment: What "doesn't work"?  What do you see if you `echo "UPDATE users SET lastlogindate = NOW() WHERE username = '$username'";`?  Have you checked for any errors from the database?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Do you set $_SESSION['username'] elsewhere? Can you echo or var_dump $username and/or $_SESSION['username'] to see that they are set prior to update attempt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set `$row` into `$_SESSION['user']` in login.php and then fetch that by `$_SESSION['username']` by mistake, you should use `$_SESSION['user']` instead.

Try this :

```
<?php
    include ("config.php"); 
    session_start();    
    $username = $_SESSION['user'];
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET lastlogindate = NOW() WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $username['username']);
    $stmt->execute();
?>
```

Comment: Dosen't add date to table unfortunately. Maybe $_SESSION username doesn't bring up the logged on users username.

Comment: Nothing mate...probably my issue :(

Comment: Changed username to user and got output of Array...now im confused

Comment: When I do print_r it shows Array ( [username] => [user] => Array ( [id] => 7 [username] => deason [email] => deasonuk@googlemail.com ) )

Comment: No luck...its like I have the two USERNAME within the session array.

Comment: Nope..Var dump comes back with string(0) ""

Comment: THat was it, it returns string(0) ""

Comment: I've added in the login.php that I understand starts the SESSION, this is the php called on my main login page

Comment: I've addded the login.php which is where i call sessions.

Comment: The problem was about that you passed an array into SESSION not a variable. `$row` in login.php is an array. That's it... Please give me +1 if you didn't before :D